# Upper bound on maximum of probabilities

Tags: probability

I read the following recently:

$\max_i P(\{a_i\neq a_i^*\})\le P(\exists i:a_i\neq a_i^*)$

I don't see why the above is true. What is the proof? How tight is this bound?

Comment: What are the sequences $\{a_i\}$, and $a_i^*$? Is there a specified distribution or measure?

Comment: Let $E_i$ be the event that $a_i\neq a_i^*$. Your inequality says that
$$
\max_i P(E_i)\le P\left(\bigcup_i E_i\right)
$$
But this follows since $E_i\subset \bigcup_i E_i$ for all $i$, so $P(E_i)\le P\left(\bigcup_i E_i\right)$, so in particular the largest $P(E_i)$ is at most $P\left(\bigcup_i E_i\right)$.